# AngularJS - Pass some flag from html to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller

I am new to Angular JS. Am stuck, and could not find a solution.

Problem - I have a html code as given below :

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-model={{tt="a"}}>
</div>
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-model={{tt="b"}}>
</div>
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-model={{tt="c"}}>
</div>
```

And a controller code is :

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    if($scope.tt == "a") //do something
    else if($scope.tt == "b) //do something else
})
```

NOTE - The html ng-model, I just wrote to let you know what i actually want.

Question - I want to send something to controller from my html, so that i can check the value and do conditionally.

Comment: U can use 'ng-if'... there is no point in assigning model to div tag

Comment: This is not clear at all. `ng-model` is used on form controls. Also why are there 3 instances of same controller? Please provide an explanation in words of what it is you are wanting to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best practice but if you want to bring data in from the html to angular you can stash the data as a property of `window` inside of a `<script>` tag.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.tt = window.data;
})
```

```html
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    {{tt}}
  </div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
  window.data='abcd';
</script>
```